# SVN keyword expansion--replace once?

Tags: svn, keyword, keyword-expansion

Svn can replace certain keywords with expanded info, like `$Rev$` to `$Rev: 123$`.

But the next time the document is changed and submitted, this replacement will get replaced once more, to the rev of the second submit.

**Is it possible to have "write-once" expansion without having to write custom submit hook scripts?**

This is for a list of info attached to revisions, think "like a changelog"

```
$Rev$: Created Info file
```

would become

```
$Rev: 1$ Created Info file
```

then

```
$Rev: 1$ Created Info file
$Rev$ Info for this revision
```

would become

```
$Rev: 1$ Created Info file
$Rev: 2$ Info for this revision
```

... etc.

If I understand the docs correctly, it would become

```
$Rev: 2$ Created Info file
$Rev: 2$ Info for this revision
```

instead, which of course isn't what I want.

Comment: No, this is not possible without any work from your site. As long as the property "svn:keyword" is set, the specified keywords will be replaced.

Comment: What benefit would having this ability be? It sounds like you're trying to do something akin to CVS's `$Log$`, which [is not going to happen in Subversion and understanding why may be helpful](https://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#log-in-source)

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by @royalTS in comments, what you want to do is not possible without any work from your side (for example an additional script removing the $...). As long as the property `svn:keyword` is set, the specified keywords will be all replaced.

As indicated by @alroc in comments, it sounds like you're trying to do something akin to CVS's $Log$, which is not going to be implemented in Subversion as explained clearly in https://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#log-in-source.

Thanks to @royalTS and @alroc.

Comment: Thanks, Laurent, royalTS and alroc, that's what I thought :/

I wanted to use this for maintaining a list of manual todos (as in what you have to do when you update to it) necessary per revision, but since you don't know your revision at the time of your submit, that would've been a convenient feature to earmark your entry. Ah well.